# Dynamically Create an Array in C#

Tags: c#

How can I dynamically create an array in C#?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Please show some pseudocode of what you are trying.

Comment: Do you mean that you should be able to resize the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `new` operator just like with other object types:

```
int[] array = new int[5];
```

or, with a variable:

```
int[] array = new int[someLength];
```

Comment: This is not quite dynamic is it?

Comment: Why not? You can use a variable instead of a literal 5 there.

Comment: once defined, you will need to re-initiate the array in order to add more than 5 items

Comment: That's correct - however, the OP asked about dynamic creation of arrays, not necessarily about the ability to dynamically grow an array.

Answer (score 24):

I'd like to add to Natrium's answer that generic collections also support this .ToArray() method.

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
stringList.Add("1");
stringList.Add("2");
stringList.Add("3");
string[] stringArray = stringList.ToArray();
```

Comment: As a note, they support ToArray() because internally, list is just plain using an immutable array and growing it with new allocations as needed.

Answer (score 8):

First make an arraylist. Add/remove items. And then `ArrayList.ToArray()`

And there is your array!

Answer (score 7):

```
object foo = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(byte), length);
```

Answer (score 7):

Ok so array initialisation gets me *every single time*.  so I took 10 minutes to do this right.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String[] as1 = new String[] { "Static", "with", "initializer" };
        ShowArray("as1", as1);

        String[] as2 = new String[5];
        as2[0] = "Static";
        as2[2] = "with";
        as2[3] = "initial";
        as2[4] = "size";
        ShowArray("as2", as2);

        ArrayList al3 = new ArrayList();
        al3.Add("Dynamic");
        al3.Add("using");
        al3.Add("ArrayList");
        //wow! this is harder than it should be
        String[] as3 = (String[])al3.ToArray(typeof(string));
        ShowArray("as3", as3);

        List<string> gl4 = new List<string>();
        gl4.Add("Dynamic");
        gl4.Add("using");
        gl4.Add("generic");
        gl4.Add("list");
        //ahhhhhh generic lubberlyness :)
        String[] as4 = gl4.ToArray();   
        ShowArray("as4", as4);
    }

    private static void ShowArray(string msg, string[] x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
        for(int i=0;i<x.Length;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("item({0})={1}",i,x[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use generic List or ArrayList.

Answer (score -1):

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

for (int i=0;i<=array.Length-1 ;i++ ) {
  Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
}
```